# Correct way to use a gerund phrase

Tags: adverbs, gerund-clauses

I have learned that adverbs should be at the end of a sentence.

What is the subject of this sentence? Is it `Using a comma after and in a list`?

Is there any adverb modifying the noun or of which members is this sentence composed?

Which of these sentences is correct?

> Using a comma after "and" in a list is optional.

or

> Using a comma after "and" is optional in a list.

Comment: I'd say moving ***in a list*** to the end could better carry the implication *...but it's **mandatory** in other contexts,* but it's a fine point. Both sequences are fine (and both are potentially ambiguous as regards implied scope).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are fine.  A gerund phrase acts like a typical noun, and here the entire phrase *"Using a comma after 'and'"* is the subject of either sentence. *"In a list"* is an adverbial phrase that describes where the subject is "optional".

Other examples:

> Climbing the Alps is recommended when visiting Switzerland.
>
> Dancing the merengue is generally easiest for beginners.